# Asp.Net 4.0 Async Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that seems to work perfectly well in development.

```cs
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 3600;
```

One of the pages uses an update panel and a web service (web client). Despite setting the timeout above, I still get the following on the server:

```
at System.Web.HttpContext.Invoke Cancellable Callback(WaitCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.LegacyAsyncPageBeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I noticed on the ASPX page it's set to `async=true`. I don't know why or what it brings to the party in this instance, but I've removed it and the site still works.

The page also has a `Response.Redirect` with the `bool end` set to `false`.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what the async could be there for? Also any indicators on the error would be appreciated too.

Comment: All you provided was a stack trace, get the errror to happen again and this time get the output of `ex.ToString()` or if you can get it to happen with the debugger attached click [Copy Exception Details to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and paste the full exception data here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott. Firstly, I can't make the error occur on my dev - it's seems to only happen on live. Also, despite putting error trapping on what seems like every other line, it still fails silently and I've been unable to pin it down.

Comment: Well however you got the stack trace we need more info, we need the type of the exception, the execption message, and possibly any inner exception detials.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having the code is fully encapsulated with try catches, and the specific error is caught at each important step. The stack trace comes from the server manager - apparently there's bug related to this message, but asp.net 2 not 4. Whatever I do I can't get it to report an error throigh my own try catch.

Comment: I have a feeling that the response redirect may be causing the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this - now working perfectly, so here how.

The problem was that I had a long running webservice-although it could be any long running job.

I added a timeout to my webclient (custom), and because I was using update panels, I also added:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 600;
```

However this still wasn't enough. The key was also put an extended time out on the page request itself:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
```

Hope this helps others.